# Clearing all widgets of a root widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am encountering an issue with my code in kivy with python 3.7:

A part of my .py code:

```
class PokemonWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PokemonWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.form_button = ObjectProperty(None)
        self.type_grid = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def create_form_buttons(self, count, form_list):
        e = 0
        for i in range(count):
            self.form_button = Button(text=form_list[e])
            self.type_grid.add_widget(self.form_button)
            e += 1

    def delete_form_buttons(self):
        self.type_grid.clear_widgets()
```

part of the .kv code:

```
<PokemonWindow>:
    name: "pokemonWindow"
    search_field: search_field
    search_button: search_button
    type_grid: type_grid

    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Main toolbar"

    MDFloatLayout:
        MDTextField:
            id: search_field
            mode: "rectangle"
            hint_text: "Pokemon name"
            size_hint_x: .6
            size_hint_y: .05
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .38, "y": 0.875}

        MDRaisedButton:
            id: search_button
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .025
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .85, "y": 0.884}
            text: "Search"
            on_press: root.create_buttons(root.get_searched_pokemon_forms(search_field.text)[0], root.get_searched_pokemon_forms(search_field.text)[1])

    MDGridLayout:
        id: type_grid
        rows: 2
        cols: 4
        size_hint_x: .8
        size_hint_y: .05
        pos_hint: {"x": .1, "y": .8}
```

Basically I am calling the create_form_buttons() method, which creates a few buttons, after entering a string into a text input field (search_field) and then clicking a button (search_button).

When I call the create_form_buttons() method again, I want the last created buttons to be removed and new buttons to appear, so I thought I'd create a method (delete_form_buttons()), that removes all widgets of the MDGridLayout (type_grid) and implemented it like so:

```
def create_form_buttons(self, count, form_list):
        e = 0
        self.delete_form_buttons()
        
        for i in range(count):
            self.form_button = Button(text=form_list[e])
            self.type_grid.add_widget(self.form_button)
            e += 1
```

When I call the method now the second time, I get this error:

```
kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayoutException: Too many children in GridLayout. Increase rows/cols!
```

I do understand the Error - it basically tells me that the new buttons would not fit into my type_grid widget, which means that the old buttons were not removed correctly I think.

So, I tried putting the delete_form_buttons() method on an on_press event of a new button like this:

```
MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Del btns"
        md_bg_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        size_hint_x: .4
        size_hint_y: .2
        pos_hint: {"x": .525, "y": .275}
        on_press: root.delete_form_buttons()
```

If I press this button with the buttons from the create_form_buttons() method being present, they disappear. But when I try to call the create_form_buttons() method again, I get the same error as I mentioned above. I dont really understand why. Could anybody please explain to me why that happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: maybe you should keep widgets on list and use `del widget` or maybe there is `widget.destroy()`. Or if it use `grid.add_widget()` then maybe it needs `grid.remove_widget(widget)`

Comment: how do you run this function? What value do you have in `count` ? Maybe it is too big? You could use `print()` to check values in variable in place which makes problem. It is called `'print debuging'`

Comment: you could use `for text in form_list: ... Button(text=text)` instead of `for i in range(count):` and then you don't need `e = 0`, `e += 1`

Answer (score 1):

Properties must be defined outside methods in classes. Try changing:

```
class PokemonWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PokemonWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.form_button = ObjectProperty(None)
        self.type_grid = ObjectProperty(None)
```

to:

```
class PokemonWindow(Screen):
    form_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    type_grid = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PokemonWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but it did not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

@furas: Thank you, I was able to shorten my code with your advice and I realized that I didnt empty the list the buttons were created from (self.get_searched_pokemon_forms[0]).

After fixing this my .py code now looks like this:

```
    def create_form_buttons(self):
        self.delete_form_buttons()

        for text in self.searched_pokemon_forms:
            btn = Button(text=text)
            self.type_grid.add_widget(btn)

        del self.searched_pokemon_forms[:]

    def delete_form_buttons(self):
        self.type_grid.clear_widgets()

    def form_button_handler(self):
        self.get_searched_pokemon_forms(self.search_field.text)
        self.create_buttons()
```

and the changed .kv code:

```
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: search_button
        size_hint_x: .2
        size_hint_y: .025
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .85, "y": 0.884}
        text: "Search"
        on_press: root.form_button_handler()
```

So now the buttons get deleted before new ones get created and after the creation of new ones, the list that holds the names gets emptied.

Thank you!